# Part of URL value tracking in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i have for example this URL

```
www.mypage/SessionPage.aspx?session=session%202#b
```

using this code i can track the complet URL

```
 _gaq.push(['pageTrackerTime._trackEvent', 'category', 'action', document.location.href, roundleaveSiteEnd]);
```

BUt i would like only to take part of it like `session%202`

is there a way to do this in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression

```
function getSessionId() {
  var re = /session=([^&=]+)/g;
  var match = re.exec(document.location.href);
  if (match) {
     var sessionId = match[1];
     return sessionId;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: You can create a JavaScript function to eval the sessionId. Now I update the post with an example.